# Is Earth Science education off topic?

Tags: discussion

IE, questions about Earth Science graduate school, field camp, curriculum, teaching in Earth Science. Is the SE purely for the discussion of the science itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It really depends on the question.** If it's just coincidentally related to school, then it's fine.

Examples:

- *My student asked me this question: [insert question].* **Good!**
- *My student is failing the class, how can I help him succeed?* **Not really...**
- *Where should we go on a feild trip?* **Too localized.**
- *How can I demonstrate [insert topic] to my students?* **Good, although may not get as much attention as other questions.**

Some that don't fit here might work fine on **[Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)**. We just need to make sure that it's on the topic of science and not general teaching, and it's useful to more than two or three users of our site.

Answer (score 5):

I would say we should allow such questions. Teaching is a part of every science and integral to the science itself. For geology field trips are also an essential part. If I am looking for a good spot for a regional geology excursion I should be able to ask if anybody knows a good outcrop.

Comment: Hmm, I agree with that specific example, but... I would say "Where is a good spot for a field camp that aims to cover topics x,y & z" is on topic, but perhaps "How should I best teach students about topic a" isn't - since that question is about the teaching rather than the science.

Comment: @SimonW Mm... it really depends on the question. *Where is a good spot for a field camp that aims to cover topics x,y & z* is kinda localized, so I'm not sure if it would be specific enough for the site.